# A very trivial ring homomorphism question!

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Ok this question maybe very trivial for all the math geniuses here, but as a beginner, it is not that trivial to me. So, here it goes...

Consider the rings $\mathbb{Z}_{3} = \{[0],[1],[2]\}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{6} = \{\bar{0},\bar{1},...\bar{5}\}$ defined $h: \mathbb{Z}_{3} \to \mathbb{Z}_{6}$ by $h([0]) = \bar{0}, h([1]) = \bar{4}, h([2]) = \bar{2}$.

Determine whether $h$ is a ring homomorphism.

Before I attempt to do this, I need to understand the question. I mean how does one get $h([1]) = \bar{4}$ and so on...? Do you do it like this... $h([1+1]) = h(\bar{1}) + h(\bar{1})$ = not sure... Please help!(Once again, I am really sorry for asking such a trivial question here)

Comment: I assume it's telling you "hey, consider this function that I feel like talking about, and see if it's a ring homomorphism."

Comment: h is a function which is given to you.So as h is a function it should be defined on whole of the domain of h.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel I must set the record straight: this *is* a ring homomorphism. Since both rings are commutative, it suffices to check 6 sums and 6 products. Since the sums and products involving the additive identity are trivial to verify, I will exhibit the remaining 3 sums and products:

$h([1]+[1]) = h([2]) = \overline{2} = \overline{4} + \overline{4} = h([1]) + h([1])$

$h([1]+[2]) = h([0]) = \overline{0} = \overline{4} + \overline{2} = h([1]) + h([2])$

$h([2]+[2]) = h([1]) = \overline{4} = \overline{2} + \overline{2} = h([2]) + h([2])$

---

$h([1]\cdot[1]) = h([1]) = \overline{4} = \overline{4}\cdot\overline{4} = h([1])\cdot h([1])$

$h([1]\cdot[2]) = h([2]) = \overline{2} = \overline{4}\cdot\overline{2} = h([1])\cdot h([2])$

$h([2]\cdot[2]) = h([1]) = \overline{4} = \overline{2}\cdot\overline{2} = h([2])\cdot h([2])$

QED